# Random "Assertion failed" errors on Apple M1 chip

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, yarnpkg, apple-m1

I have just switched from Windows 10 to Mac OS running on the latest Apple M1 Silicon.

This is my first project on the Mac, I installed **homebrew** and used it to install both **node** & **yarn**:

```
brew install node
brew install yarn
yarn global add @vue/cli
```

My Vue project was working fine on both Windows and Linux, cloned it onto my Macbook then ran `yarn` to install dependencies (business as usual) then tried running the app in development mode:

```
yarn serve
```

But I kept getting random "Assertion failed" errors each time I run `yarn serve`, each time it's a different file but the same error message and context:

```
/node_modules/axios/lib/helpers/buildURL.jsAssertion failed: (thread_id_key != 0x7777), function find_thread_id_key, file ../src/coroutine.cc, line 134.
error Command failed with signal "SIGABRT".
```

What's causing this? Tried Googling but as I thought, found literally nothing!

Comment: Are you low on memory?

Comment: @spender Not actually, I am peaking at 2GB of memory usage.

Answer (score 9):

I have managed to fix the issue.

The problem was that one of the dependencies (node-fibers) isn't compatible with nodejs v16.0.0 or later.

So the solution was to uninstall node and install NVM to use Node v15.

---

First had to uninstall Yarn & Node:

```
brew uninstall yarn
brew uninstall node
```

Then installed NVM:

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/master/install.sh | bash
```

After that I installed Node v15 (or whatever version you'd prefer):

```
nvm install v15
```

Comment: Awesome that you came back to self-answer. Nice.

Comment: @spender It's the least I could do to the community that has been helping me for 13 years since I was 11 years old tinkering with app development and continues to help me still!

Comment: Another +1 from me for helping another tinkerer such as yourself :D Only thing I'd add is to maybe use `curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/master/install.sh | bash` since that will always give you the latest stable version.

Comment: @Kenny83 Thanks Kenny, edited the answer to use your tip.